# Remove non-ASCII and specific characters from a dataframe column using Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I would to clean up data in a dataframe column City.
It can have the following values:

VeniceÂ®
VeniceÆ
Venice?
Venice
<sup>Venice<sup>Â®</sup>
Venice</sup>

I would like to remove all the non ascii characters as well as ?,  and .
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Python 3 strings are Unicode. There are no "non-ASCII" characters. Even `Venice` is 6 Unicode characters. What you posted is the result of reading a UTF8 file using the wrong encoding. To fix this *use the correct encoding*. Post the code you used to load this file, and post an *actual* example of the correct text

Comment: In UTF8 characters outside the 7-bit US-ASCII range are represented as two or more bytes. If you try to read UTF8 text using eg Latin1 the extra bytes will appear as extra characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up strings with Regex by filtering only on letters

```
# create dataframes
date_data = [
    (1,"VeniceÂ®"),
    (2,"VeniceÆ"),
    (3,"Venice?"),
    (4,"Venice")]

schema = ["id","name"]
df_raw = spark.createDataFrame(data=date_data, schema = schema)
df_raw.show()

+---+--------+
|id |name    |
+---+--------+
|1  |VeniceÂ®|
|2  |VeniceÆ |
|3  |Venice? |
|4  |Venice  |
+---+--------+

# apply regular expression
df_clean=(df_raw.withColumn("clean_name",f.regexp_replace(f.col("name"), "[^a-zA-Z]", "")))
df_clean.show()

+---+--------+----------+
| id|    name|clean_name|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|VeniceÂ®|    Venice|
|  2| VeniceÆ|    Venice|
|  3| Venice?|    Venice|
|  4|  Venice|    Venice|
+---+--------+----------+
```

PS: But I doubt that you see such characters after correct import to spark. Superscript for example is ignored